# Unfortunately softkeyboard has stopped working

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-softkeyboard

I have made a SoftKeyboard with dictionary support. The keyboard runs fine on some devices but on some devices it says-" unfortunately SoftKeyboard has stopped working" when tried to set as default keyboard. When I tested in on emulator the following logcat error messages shows up:-

```
04-23 14:48:52.636 3389-3414/com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for      com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
04-23 14:48:52.636 3389-3414/com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard E/BinaryDictionaryGetter: Could not find a dictionary pack
04-23 14:48:52.646 3389-3414/com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard E/dalvikvm: dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard-1/libjni_latinime.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "getpagesize" referenced by "libjni_latinime.so"...
04-23 14:48:52.646 3389-3414/com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard E/JniUtils: Could not load native library jni_latinime
04-23 14:48:52.675 3389-3414/com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: InitializeBinaryDictionary
                                                                       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard.BinaryDictionary.openNative:(Ljava/lang/String;JJIIII)J
                                                                           at com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard.BinaryDictionary.openNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard.BinaryDictionary.loadDictionary(BinaryDictionary.java:100)
                                                                           at com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard.BinaryDictionary.<init>(BinaryDictionary.java:76)
                                                                           at com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard.DictionaryFactory.createMainDictionaryFromManager(DictionaryFactory.java:60)
                                                                           at com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard.DictionaryFactory.createMainDictionaryFromManager(DictionaryFactory.java:86)
                                                                           at com.MyKeybd.inputmethod.SoftKeyboard.Suggest$1.run(Suggest.java:137)
```

What are these error messages? If these error messages crashes the app in some devices and the emulator then how it runs fine on my phone and some other devices? Please help me